# Page numeration without LIMIT statement and with sorting

Tags: php, mysql

I have an article system which is used by several users. Articles have their own permissions which gets checked against the viewer's ID for each article that runs through my while loop. I limit the articles by incrementing `$printcount` if the user is allowed to view the article, and the loop terminates when it reaches `$limit`. I also have sorting options to sort by name, date inserted, date modified and submitted by.

How would I go about utilizing next/previous page buttons without using MySQL limit features? Here is a short version of my code (may not be 100% functional, but should bring the point across)

```
<?php
$sort=$_GET['sort']; // date_added
$direction=$_GET['dir']; // ASC
$limit=$_GET['limit']; // 25
$query="SELECT * FROM `article` ORDER BY '$sort' '$direction'";

$result=mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)==NULL) {
  echo '<tr><td colspan="4">NO RECORDS FOUND</td></tr>';
}
$printcount=0;
while(($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))&&($printcount<$limit+1)) {
  //if user is owner of article $readable=true;
  //load permissions from permission column (comma separated integers) into array, if user's group ID is in that array $readable=true;
  //if article "global_read" flag=1, $readable=true;
  //if $printcount<$limit, and $readable echo the table row with data
  //if $readable, $printcount++;
}
?>
```

If I were only sorting by `ID ASC`, I could easily store the ID as a `last_id`, and on next page the query would have an additional: `` WHERE `id` > $last_ID ``, but since there are different sort options and direction options this seems to be much more complicated.

Comment: I think a question that needs to be addressed is *why*.  Why would you want/need to do this?

Comment: Without `LIMIT`, you may as well have the application server handle it so you don't have to keep fetching the same data from the database.

Comment: I have built an in-house wiki that restricts access to groups of users. I have a groups table which stores the user IDs that are part of the group in a string, separated by commas. I didn't want to have a dedicated permissions table with an entry for every single article as my application could potentially crawl after several thousand entries. I am not sure how else to approach this other than using flat files with it's own permission set built-in. This is my first attempt incorporating a permissions system, and I am currently using  explode/implode on the string to and from the database

Comment: I have figured out how to use a separate table to achieve what I needed while keeping the limits in the MySQL query. Example query:

Comment: SELECT `rows` FROM `articles` WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `article_id` FROM `article_permissions` WHERE `permission_flag`=0 AND `read_access`=1) OR `id` IN (SELECT `article_id` FROM `article_permissions` WHERE `permission_flag`=1 AND `target_id`=$GROUP_ID AND `read_access`=1); -- works like a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're asking this question because your permission model is handled in the php application and prevents you from easily using LIMIT in your queries.

You should store the per-user permissions in the database table, and then use a join so that only the articles that a user can view are retrieved. Then you don't have to handle the pagination or sorting logic in your application; you can just use LIMIT and ORDER BY in mysql to do it for you.

Also you should probably use the parameter-based queries. Your code has a massive sql injection hole.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The above script ($_GET vars) are not actually used, just used for easier reading. I strictly check all variables before putting them in an SQL query.

Comment: I decided to go with per-article style permissions table, with 6 columns: the permission PK, article's ID (FK), an integer flag used to determine the type of permission (global permission, group permission, and user permission), a Target ID integer (FK) to reference the corresponding group or user ID, and a read/write tinyint (0 for no access, 1 for access).

Answer (score 0):

The good (stable, fast) pagination uses no OFFSET but keeps LIMIT so the user can move from page to page and response time won't increase as they move to further pages
This document is very educational about pagination (uses MySQL but the main ideas can also be considered in other dbms).

[Pagination in MySQL](http://www.percona.com/ppc2009/PPC2009_mysql_pagination.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for that document, however I already understand how to make a fast pagation concept in the basic form. The problem here is adding permission checks to see if group(s) and user(s) have access to view the contents. This is how I had my script before but since I was using LIMIT, the # of results do not accurately represent the number of visible articles as the query has no idea I am doing permission checks. I guess I am looking for a practical solution to incorporate multiple groups and/or user permissions effectively that can also scale up. Thanks again though!

Comment: Ugh, in that case I would support jonchang's answer.